# How to use 2 formsets and save them (POST METHOD ISSUES)

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, validation

This is the thing, i have 2 formsets in one django template, to validate the formset, django use management data to validate the formset like the following:

```
'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '1',
'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
```

but when i want to post both formsets at the same time, they need two different validation data because, for example, my first formset have 1 form when i submit and the second formset have 2 forms made so the first one needs a data like the one above but the second one needs the "TOTAL_FORMS" value of two, but the post just sent ONE validation data, so just one formset is valid and the other dont. If you have the same number of forms in both formsets (first one with one form and second one with one form also), they pass the validation because the management data works for both.

my template is the following

```
{% extends 'prescription_menu.html' %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}site/css/select2.css"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}Physicians{% endblock title %}

% block container %}
{% csrf_token %}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">

            {% crispy person_form  %}
            {% crispy employee_form  %}
            {% crispy physician_form %}
            {% crispy address_form %}
            {% crispy phone_form %}
        <form id="otherForm" method="POST">
            <legend>Specialties</legend>
            {{ spec_formset.management_form }}
            {{ ac_de_formset.management_form }}
            {% for specialty, degree in SDU %}
                    {% crispy specialty helper %}
                    {% crispy degree helper %}
                <legend></legend>
            {% endfor %}
        </form>
        <form id="emailsForm" method="POST">
            {{ em_formset.management_form }}
            {% for email in em_formset %}
                {% crispy email helper %}
            {% endfor %}
        </form>




        <input type="button" name="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-id-save" onclick="submitForms()">
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock container %}


{% block javascript %}
<script>
submitForms = function(){
    document.getElementById("otherForm").submit();
    document.getElementById("emailsForm").submit();
}
</script>
{% endblock javascript %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `prefix` argument when constructing your formsets in the view to make your two formsets not share a namespace, eg:

```
spec_formset = SomeFormsetClass(prefix="spec")
ac_de_formset = SomeOtherFormsetClass(prefix="ac_de")
```

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/#using-more-than-one-formset-in-a-view) have the full details.